# understanding a Haskell function with filter and lambda expressions

Tags: list, haskell, filter

```
j :: [Int]
j = filter ((\h x -> h x > x) (\y -> y*y)) [-2,-1,0,1,2]
```

This one outputs `[-2,-1,2]` but why? could someone please explain me step by step what Haskell does here to get this output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It filters the list in the function (`[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]`) by a predicate, the predicate is the expression `((\h x -> h x > x) (\y -> y*y))`.

We here see two *lambda expressions*. The former takes as input two parameters `h` and `x`, and returns `True` if `h x` is greater than `x`. The second one takes as input a parameter `y`, and returns `y*y` (so it squares the input).

The second lambda expression is taken as first parameter of the first lambda expression, so that means that:

```
  ((\h x -> h x > x) (\y -> y*y))
-----------------------------------
= \x -> (\y -> y*y) x > x
```

So a function that takes as input a variable `x` and returns `True` if and only if `(\y -> y*y) x` is greater than `x`. We can again reduce that function further with:

```
  \x -> (\y -> y*y) x > x
-------------------------
= \x -> x*x > x
```

So it is a predicate that checks if `x*x > x` for a given `x`, or "*the variable should be less than the square of that variable*".

So we here filter the list `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]` such that only elements where its square is greater are retained. So if we evaluate this we see that:

```
  x|x*x|x*x > x
---+---+-------
 -2|  4| True  
 -1|  1| True  
  0|  0| False 
  1|  1| False 
  2|  4| True
```

So the result is `[-2, -1, 2]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
(\h x -> h x > x) (\y -> y*y)
```

Is equivalent to

```
\x -> x*x > x
```

So you just need to square every number on your list and compare it to the original to see why the output is like it is:

```
-- original:   [-2, -1,  0,  1,  2]
-- squared:    [ 4,  1,  0,  1,  4]
-- comparison: [ T,  T,  F,  F,  T]
```

This predicate will return `True` for every negative number (because every negative number squared is positive, and so greater than the original, and for every positive number larger than 1. Since you're operating on `Int`s, this means that `0` and `1` are the only numbers that will fail that predicate.